# meaning of "on the doll"

Tags: meaning

A [post](https://www.quora.com/What-is-your-opinion-of-data-management-experts) says

> Can you show me **on the doll** where the bad data management expert touched you?

Wiki gives this explanation about "on the doll"

> The film's title comes from the phrase "Show me on the doll where you were touched", often asked of young children who have been the victims of sexual abuse. The film covers multiple lives of victims and victimizers, sharing the pain of how early childhood traumas can continue throughout adult lives.

I guess I understand the explanation. The question is about the usage.

When would someone said something like that to another person, besides the actual police-victim situation?

Would the use in first quotation be considered as an interesting expression, or some kind of impolite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase was used as sarcasm, to imply that the person it was directed at could be compared to a defenseless child who was victimized by a "data management expert" who molested him.
Presumably, the writer thinks that the reader is acting like a baby, and should take responsibility for themselves and stop complaining.

I guess it's clever, but it seems tasteless to me.